# Raspberry Pi NOOBS not working

Tags: pi-3, noobs

I am trying to install Raspbian with NOOBS. I downloaded the offline w/ network version (**not** the lite version), unzipped it, and copied and pasted the files into a formatted 32GB microSD card (formatted with the SD Formatter Tool from the SD Association). Then I safely ejected it from my computer and inserted it into my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, connected the USB mouse and USB keyboard, and connected it to a television using an HDMI cable. I connect the power adapter, and it shows me the rainbow screen. Then it takes me to a new screen with the RPi logo, then provides some messages about the RPi formatting the SD card. Finally, it provides a message that it needs WiFi connection for installing other images apart from local images and then says it cannot find any WiFi interfaces. However, it does not show any available operating systems to install, not even Raspbian, which should be available since I used the offline NOOBs version. What is going on?

EDIT: I successfully installed Raspbian thanks to CoderMike's answer. However, I never figured out why NOOBs was not working.

Comment: Please add the URL you have downloaded from. Have you verified the sha checksum?

Comment: @Fabian https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest

Comment: The given URL is a dynamic redirect to a random mirror, the downloaded file may be broken. Try `https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS/images/NOOBS-2018-03-14/NOOBS_v2_7_0.zip` and verify the checksum with `sha256sum /path/to/downloaded/NOOBS_v2_7_0.zip`, it should be `b145c7c28f2ba912fc0e4bf866fd9ef8e9e8d4b94dad76d522e3361447c99e5d` for version  2.7.0, release date 2018-03-14 (see https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/ ).

Comment: @Fabian I will try to download the zip file with the provided link but the ones I downloaded had the correct sha checksum so it's probably the correct file, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want Raspbian don't bother with Noobs.

1. Download Rasbian Stretch with Desktop https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
2. Flash Raspbian (no need to unzip) to sd card using Etcher https://etcher.io
3. Place sd card in Pi and boot