# NOOBS not downloading correctly

Tags: pi-zero, noobs

[image]I have recently got my first Raspberry Pi. It is a Pi 0 (without wifi). I installed NOOBS (version 2.9.0) onto my PC, then copied it across to my SD Card(formatted using the SD association formatter) where I extracted the files. Once this was done, I popped it into the Raspberry Pi. I plugged the HDMI into a monitor but no signal was recognised. I have not plugged in an ethernet as of yet. I have also tried donwloading LIBREELEC to my SD, but that shows no input too. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Did you copy the zip to the SD card before unpacking? Did you remove the zip afterwards? What files can you see on the SD after unpacking? And 8GB is fairly small for Noobs + Raspbian Desktop.

Comment: I zipped it once it was already on the SD card is that important?

Comment: `I zipped it` I assume you mean 'unzipped'. Can you answer the other questions, please?

Comment: I meant unzipped sorry, I have added a picture of the files from LIBREELEC folder, and nothing displays, however I have noticed the green activity light has turned on(didn't realise it existed), and I am fairly certain that it wasn't on before

Comment: Are those the contents of the card after unzipping? And are those all the files? That looks more like Noobs Lite (unless it's something completely different). If you don't have a working internet connection you cannot install an OS.

Comment: no, that is libre elec straight from  https://libreelec.tv/downloads/

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I'm trying to diagnose your Noobs problem and not getting answers to relevant questions. Good luck with getting this solved.

Comment: Not sure how, but I changed the plug(for about the tenth time) and it turned on randomly, a week after giving up. I changed it back to the original plug and it  actually works now. Something about the plug must be dodgy where it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after Raspbian (recommended OS) - don't bother with Noobs.

1. Download Raspbian Stretch with Desktop
   https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
2. Flash to sd card using Etcher https://etcher.io (no need to format, nor unzip)
3. Place in Pi and turn on

Comment: I'm mainly after LIBREELEC, but would like to have it from NOOBS instead of downloading it straight

Comment: Btw, I did everything https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81997/raspberry-pi-noobs-not-working/82004#82004 does, but I do not get a screen to show up, and my SD card is only 8gb. Also, does it matter that I am using a TV instead of a standard monitor?

Comment: For the initial boot, I don't need to plug ethernet in do I? I highly doubt it will make a difference to turn it on will it?

Comment: @Nainman: if you want to install Raspbian and LibreELEC you will need a network connection straight away. Only Raspbian is delivered with Noobs full and other OSs need to be downloaded. 8GB will probably not be enough.

Comment: What power supply are you using? Have you selected the hdmi input on the TV? Are the hdmi cables plugged in tightly?

Comment: im using a phone charger, and the hdmi is plugged in tight, when I plug it into my laptop, the hdmi on the tv works

Comment: I always use the official power supply. Is the hdmi input selected when you power up the Pi Zero. btw update your question with all of your responses.

Comment: I've tried the actual LIBREELEC too, but that doesn't display anything either

Answer (score 0):

What does "I installed NOOBS onto my PC" mean? You CAN NOT installed NOOBS on a PC.
Is there any reason you DID NOT follow the instructions on the [Foundation site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)?

NOTE you will need at least a 16GB SD Card for Raspbian and LIBREELEC.

Personally I wouldn't use NOOBS but [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) - which is functionally similar, but more efficient and flexible.